# when click on jquery second time not working

Tags: html, jquery

Prepaid

$(document).on('click','.prepaid_button',function(){

var sevcount=parseInt($('#services_count').val());

servcount=servcount+1;
$('#services_count').val(servcount);

});

Comment: Please see [ask] to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The variable name : **sevcount** changed to **servcount** which make the error.

I rename all the variable to **sevcount**

```js
$(document).on('click','.prepaid_button',function(){
     
     var sevcount=parseInt($('#services_count').val());
      sevcount=sevcount+1; 
      $('#services_count').val(sevcount);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prepaid_button" > BUTTON </div>

<input id="services_count" value="0" >
```

Welcome to our community @syam, Glad to welcoming you.